# REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD error in git remote push Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans

I'm working on a remote git, and find a remote that I'm trying to PUSH to send my new changes to the other remote (for joining origin / master) and even sending a PULL or PUSH Pull from upstream in the screen is locked in image screen
[image]
advancing already hangs on the screen, I want to do: take a PULL, MERGE and then send my new files with PUSH. How to proceed? `I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.0 (windows) .` After this , this shows the error:
[image]
And in final output:

```
Remote Repository Updates
    Branch Update : master
    Old Id        : 0000000hgfh0000fdffgg1f32g1fdg2fd1gd1g2fd
    New Id        : 0000dsadda000hgfh06546f32g1fdg2fd1gd1g2fd
    Result        : REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD
    Local Repository Updates
    Branch Update : origin/master
    Old Id        : 0000000hgfh0000fdffgg1f32g1fdg2fd1gd1g2fd
    New Id        : 0000dsadda000hgfh06546f32g1fdg2fd1gd1g2fd
    Result        : NOT_ATTEMPTED
    ==[IDE]== 24/06/2015 21:54:14 Pushing
```

Comment: The error in the pop-up is pretty self-explanatory, isn't it? Someone else has beaten you pushing to master; if you want to push your new code to master you'll have to fetch or pull theirs and merge it into yours before you can push the combined code. The resulting merge commit will be a descendant of the current master, which is what the server needs before it can advance master ('fast-forward') to the new commit.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pull first since the remote has new commits that you do not have locally. You are attempting to push.

Comment: I wish there were some way to forgoe this and just overwrite the damn Github repo. There's no *real* commit there, it's just the default README or whatev.